# Firefox и поля input password, запретить заполнение и изменение пароля для

Tags: html, form, firefox, input, password

Есть два input поля(обернуты в form), они password, в них пишут дополнительные пароли, то есть сам пароль и подтверждение. Вроде все ок, но firefox автоматически заполняет эти два поля когда это не требуется, +также он спрашивает для какого пользователя изменить пароль, как это отключить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, вам поможет добавление аттрибута

```
 autocomplete="off"
```

к указанным полям.

Подробнее про данную функцию: http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/autocomplete